# Idris - Expression doesnt typecheck when imported from module

Tags: idris, unification, type-level-computation

I have an Idris module that defines a certain type/predicate `IsSet` and a decidability function `isSet` over it. It also defines some helper functions to compute that decidability function at type-checking to obtain a proof of `IsSet`.

Expressions that use that auxiliary function typecheck correctly inside the module, but don't when I define them in another file and I import the original module:

**Test1.idr**

```
module Test1

import Data.List

%default total
%access export

data IsSet : List t -> Type where
  IsSetNil : IsSet []
  IsSetCons : Not (Elem x xs) -> IsSet xs -> IsSet (x :: xs)

ifNotSetHereThenNeitherThere : Not (IsSet xs) -> Not (IsSet (x :: xs))
ifNotSetHereThenNeitherThere notXsIsSet (IsSetCons xIsInXs xsIsSet) = notXsIsSet xsIsSet  

ifIsElemThenConsIsNotSet : Elem x xs -> Not (IsSet (x :: xs))      
ifIsElemThenConsIsNotSet xIsInXs (IsSetCons notXIsInXs xsIsSet) = notXIsInXs xIsInXs

isSet : DecEq t => (xs : List t) -> Dec (IsSet xs)
isSet [] = Yes IsSetNil
isSet (x :: xs) with (isSet xs)
  isSet (x :: xs) | No notXsIsSet = No $ ifNotSetHereThenNeitherThere notXsIsSet
  isSet (x :: xs) | Yes xsIsSet with (isElem x xs)
    isSet (x :: xs) | Yes xsIsSet | No notXInXs = Yes $ IsSetCons notXInXs xsIsSet
    isSet (x :: xs) | Yes xsIsSet | Yes xInXs = No $ ifIsElemThenConsIsNotSet xInXs

getYes : (d : Dec p) -> case d of { No _ => (); Yes _ => p}
getYes (No _ ) = ()
getYes (Yes prf) = prf

getNo : (d : Dec p) -> case d of { No _ => Not p; Yes _ => ()}
getNo (No cnt) = cnt
getNo (Yes _ ) = ()

setTest1 : IsSet ["x"]
setTest1 = getYes $ isSet ["x"]
```

**Test2.idr**

```
module Test2

import Test1

%default total
%access export

setTest2 : IsSet ["x"]
setTest2 = getYes $ isSet ["x"]
```

`setTest1` typechecks correctly but `setTest2` throws the following error:

```
When checking right hand side of setTest2 with expected type
         IsSet ["x"]

 Type mismatch between
         case block in getYes at Test1.idr:26:30 (IsSet ["x"])
                                                 (isSet ["x"])
                                                 (isSet ["x"]) (Type of getYes (isSet ["x"]))
 and
         IsSet ["x"] (Expected type)
```

I'm using Idris 0.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When type checking `Test2.idr`, the type checker does not know the **definition** (as opposed to just the type) of `isSet`, so it cannot reduce the type signature of `getYes`, hence the type mismatch. In order for this to work, you have to `public export` the function `isSet`. Due to Idris' visibility rules, you then also have to at least `public export` the `IsSet` type, because `isSet` references its (currently not exported) definition.

This is probably a good idea anyway, though, since without that, not even a simple function like

```
isNil : IsSet l -> Bool
isNil IsSetNil = True
isNil (IsSetCons f y) = False
```

in `Test2.idr` would work, since that module does not know the definition, i.e. the data constructors, of the type.

Comment: Can I make every type and definition public globally? I'm using `%access export` and I thought that was the intended use of it (export everything). Would I just need to change it,to `%access public export` maybe?

Comment: You can and that's exactly how you'd do it. I would encourage you to think about that for a moment, though. `public export` exposes the **definition** of things, which is somewhat counter to the idea of modules, i.e. hiding implementation details. You should consult what the [documentation](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/modules.html) has to say about this.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll try it. The thing with dependent types is that you don't really know when you'll need the definition for some type-level computation or not though :P

Comment: That's true, though making things `private` by default and only them (via `export`) and/or their definition (via `public export`, of course only after having thought hard about it ;)) is less likely to break existing code than changing an already exposed definition. It's a trade off, of course, but I think keeping things secret by default is a good rule of thumb and one should think about deviating from it first, IMHO.